# LinuxをもつPCが2台で、リモートアクセスにより、Xアプリの1つ「Xeyes」を表示させる方法

Tags: linux

現在、LinuxをもつPCが2台あり(PCA PCBとする)、PCAからリモートアクセスによりPCBへ、Xアプリの1つ「Xeyes」を表示させようと思います(PCAにある「Xeyes」をPCBで表示させたいという意味です。)。
しかし、現状、「Can't Open Display PCBのアドレス」というエラーがPCAに表示され、この後の解決がわかりません。

簡単な構成は以下となります。
PCA
・PC:デスクトップ型PC
・OS:Linux(CentOS 7)
・その他：XClientとする。

PCB
・PC:デスクトップ型PC
・OS:Windows10内に、VirtualBoxのLinux(CentOS 7)がある。
・その他：XServerとする。

現在設定として、以下のことを試しました。
1.PCAで 「export DISPLAY=PCBのアドレス:0.0」
2.PCBで、GUIの画面から一度「xinit」を行い、「startx」でxtermの画面
3.PCBで「xhost + PCAのアドレス」

以下参考にしています。
https://www.infraeye.com/study/linuxz37.html

以上が今までの構成と流れですが、今必要な設定は他になにかあるでしょうか(基本的にsshをしない方法で考えております、、)？
互いのip疎通は前提としてできております。
また、PCBですが、「systemctl status XServer」で調べるとXServerのServiceが「running」状態ではなかったことは気になっております。

この分野に関して初心者で分からないことが多くあります。お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

---

以下は、皆様のコメントを元に追加で行った内容です。
1.ポートを開いた状態で、xeyesが表示されるか確認
・PCBで、「startx -- -listen tcp」を行い、ポート明示的に開いてxサーバを立ち上げた。
　 明示的にポートを開かなければ、ポートが閉じた状態でxサーバが立ち上がるため。
・PCBで「firewall-cmd --add-port=6000/tcp」を行い、6000番台を立ち上げる。
・PCBで「printenv DISPLAY」でディスプレイ番号確認する。ディスプレイ番号で、「:2」を得る。
・PCBで「xhost +PCAのアドレス」をする。
・「xhost」をする。「access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect　INET:PCAのアドレス」という結果を得ており、PCAのアドレスが許可されている。
・PCBで「ss -tlpn | grep 600」を行い、ポート接続しているのは「X」であることを確認した。
・PCAで「export DISPLAY=PCBのアドレス:2.0」をする。
・PCAでxeyes起動するが、「Can't open display PCBのアドレス:2.0」で起動できない。

2.sshでxeyesが表示されるか確認
・PCBで、xサーバを立ち上げた上で、「ssh -X PCAのアドレス」でPCAにログインする。
・PCBで、xeyes起動すると表示される。

3.PCAからPCBへsshでログイン可能かどうか確認
・PCBへログインできていることを確認した。

4.PCBのアドレスはゲストマシンのアドレスか確認　
・PCBのアドレスはゲストマシンのアドレスであることが分かった。(ホストマシンWindows側のアドレスではない)

5.PCBのWindowsのファイヤーウォールを切っているか
・有償のセキュリティソフトが、windowsのファイヤーウォールを管理しているが、それが切られていることは確認した。

6.PCBで、「xhost +」で全てのマシーンを受け入れ形で、xeyesが表示されるか確認
　1.の方法を元に行ったが、xeyesは起動しなかった。

---

結果としまして、以下で恐らく可能かと思います。
追加作業1「ポートを開いた状態で、xeyesが表示されるか確認」において、2点目と3点目の作業を逆にしてください。また作業で若干の修正があります。
・PCBで「printenv DISPLAY」でディスプレイ番号確認する。ディスプレイ番号で、私のPCの場合「:2」を得る。
・PCBで「firewall-cmd --add-port=6002/tcp」を行い、6002番を立ち上げる。
　利用するディスプレイ番号が0以外の場合は、（6000+ディスプレイ番号）のポートが使われるので、立ち上げるポートの設定もディスプレイ番号に合わせて変更したほうがよいそうです。今までは、ポート番号を6000で常時設定しようとしていましたが、ディスプレイ番号は2だったのでxeysの表示ができなかったのかもしれません。しかし、ポート番号6000で設定して、「ss -tlpn」をすると、「*6002」というメッセージで6002ポートがオープンされているように思われたのですが、、
参考：https://qiita.com/kkk627/items/0a4ad6c2ccd1548474ba

上記を行うと、ポートを設定した状態でxeyesが起動できると恐らく思われます。または、PCBのファイヤーウォールを完全に停止すれば同じようにできるはずです。

助けていただいた皆様本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: ポートの問題かもしれませんね。

参考：
https://qiita.com/kkk627/items/8db34266722488eae412

Comment: なぜこんな方法を行いたいのでしょうか？ 特に理由がなければ `ssh`の X11 forwarding  で接続すれば X11アプリを描画できます (`man ssh` で詳細わかるはず)

Comment: PCB は「Windows10内に、VirtualBoxのLinux(CentOS 7)がある」とありますが、VirtualBox での NIC の設定はブリッジ接続になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: Itagaki Fumihiko さん   　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　参考を元にポートを調べて見ました。結果は変わりませんでした。また、参考で、ホストB側（私の場合PC側）でXサーバの設定を行う内容が2点あるかと思います(export DISPLAYとxhost+)。PCBで「export DISPLAY　PCBのアドレス」　を行った後に、「xhost　+PCAのアドレス」をすると、「unable to open display PCBのアドレス」というエラーを得たため、今回「export DISPLAY」という設定はしておりません。

Comment: oririさん　理由として、本番環境がそのような構成であり、模擬環境として同様の構成で実現を行いたいからです。

Comment: metropolis　さん  ブリッジアダプター設定をしております。

Comment: 構成の話ではなく, PCBから `ssh -y USER@HOST` で PCAに接続し `xeyes`起動すれば表示されるはずです (環境変数など設定も必要なく)。ssh使ってはいけないとか, どちらから接続しなければならないとか制限があるなら, 質問に追記したほうがよいかも(PCAからアクション行うのは決定？)

Comment: oririさん　ご指摘ありがとうございます。後で修正を行います。sshを使わずに行いたいと思います。また、PCAにあるxeyesアプリを、PCBに表示させたいと思っております。

Comment: 「PCAにあるxeyesアプリを、PCBに表示させたいと思っております。」… 実際に試してみればいいのでは？ その様に表示されるので。

Comment: 参考として挙げられている Qiita の記事の通り、`X server` が `-nolisten tcp` 付きで実行されているためかと思います。`sudo ss -tlpn` を実行すれば 6000 番ポートが開いている(listen されている)かどうかを確認できます。

Comment: metropolis さん　「ss -tlpn」でポートの確認を行いました。「*:6002」というのがあり、6000番台のポートが存在しているのを確認できました（参考に関しても、必ず6000番ポートが設定されるわけではないそうですね）。しかし、結果は変わらず、xeyesを起動できませんでした。

Comment: 解決に至った情報は質問に追記してしまうのではなく、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。(質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保つのが望ましいです)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントが付けられなかったので回答として投稿します。
「ss -tlpn」を実行して6002番ポートがあったとのことですが、そのポートを用いて接続しているのはXサーバのプロセスでしたか？出力結果を質問文に追記すると適切なコメントがもらえると思います。

もし接続待ちがXサーバのプロセスだったとするならば、PCAでexportするDISPLAY変数は
DISPLAY=PCBアドレス:0.0
ではなく
DISPLAY=PCBアドレス:2.0
になるかと思います。
6002番がXサーバとは関係ないプロセスであるならすでに指摘を受けている通り-nolisten tcp付きで実行されているのではと思います。

--コメントを受けて追記--
1つずつ丁寧に切り分けるしかないと思います。以下、確認済みのものもあるかと思いますが、
思いつくものを列挙しておきます。未確認のものがある場合は確認することをお勧めします。

・PCBのアドレスはゲストマシンのアドレスか？（ホストマシンWindows側のアドレスになっていないか）
・PCBでxhostコマンドを引数無しで実行して、出力される結果にPCAのアドレスが許可されているか
・PCAで「xeyes -display PCBのアドレス:2.0」を実行した場合はどうか？
・コメントで提案のあったsshによる実行ではどうか（実際のシステムで使用するかは別として動作するかしないかの確認として）

手元にすぐ動かせるLinuxマシンが準備できないので実行例など示せず申し訳ありません。

Comment: 今後出力結果を追記するようにしていきます。
「ss -tlpn | grep 600」を行った結果となります。
 State       Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port
 LISTEN      0      128                *:6002               *:*    users:(("X",pid=4851,fd=3))
 LISTEN      0      128               :::6002              :::*    users:(("X",pid=4851,fd=1))
6002のポートを用いて接続しているのはXのプロセスと思われます、、またおっしゃるように6002番がポートの場合は、ディスプレイ番号は
「2」になりそうですね。見落としていました。PCAよりPCBへ「export DISPLAY=PCBのアドレス:2.0」を行い、「xeyes」を起動しようとしましたが
ダメでした、、。

Comment: @santian 思いついたことを回答に追記しました。参考にならないかもしれませんがご確認いただければと思います。

Comment: 色々とご対応ありがとうございます。確認しました。結果が次です。・PCBのアドレスはゲストマシンのアドレスか？（ホストマシンWindows側のアドレスになっていないか）
  →PCBのアドレスはゲストマシンのアドレスです。
・PCBでxhostコマンドを引数無しで実行して、出力される結果にPCAのアドレスが許可されているか
→「access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect　INET:PCAのアドレス」という結果を得ており、PCAのアドレスが許可されていると思います。
・PCAで「xeyes -display PCBのアドレス:2.0」を実行した場合はどうか？
  →「xhost」設定、ポートの設定を行った前提で、実行できませんでした。「Can't open display PCBのアドレス:2.0」という出力を行いました。
・コメントで提案のあったsshによる実行ではどうか（実際のシステムで使用するかは別として動作するかしないかの確認として）
　→PCBで、「ssh -X PCAのアドレス」を行い、PCAにログインしました。「xeyes」を起動すると、PCB上でアプリが表示されました。xhostによる通信設定で些細なミスをしている気がします。virtualBoxそのもので問題はないかと思います。

Comment: xhostの設定は問題なさそうに思います。もし試すとすれば「xhost +」ですべて許可した状態でどうなるか確認するぐらいでしょうか。ところでPCAにログインせずPCBでxeyesを起動した場合はちゃんと表示されますか？表示される場合、echo $DISPLAYで変数の値を確認してみてください。コロン以降が「:X または :X.Y」のように表示されると思います。そこの値がPCAでexportを試したDISPLAY変数と異なる場合はコロン以降をその値にして試してみてください。

Comment: 試しました。1点目ですが、PCBで「xhost +」を行い、PCAで「xeyes」を行いました。結果は、表示されず、「Can't open display PCBのアドレス:2.0」という出力を行いました。2点目ですが、PCAにログインせずPCBで「xeyes」は表示できました。「exho $DISPLAY」の結果は「:2」で、PCAでexportしたDISPLAY変数と同じ値だと思います。

Comment: 「xhost +」でダメなのであればネットワーク構成の問題な気がしますが正直分かりませんね。あとはPCAからPCBにssh や telnet等でログイン可能かを念のため確認するぐらいでしょうか(ログインしたら間違いなくPCBのCentOS上であることも確認する）。また、追加調査した内容と結果は質問に追記した方がいいと思います。

Comment: PCB の ホストOS は Windows10 なので Windows Defender などの firewall ソフトウェアが有効になっていて当該ポートへのアクセスが禁止されている、という事はないでしょうか？

Comment: h.tokiさん　色々とお助けいただき感謝しております。先ほど追記しました。PCAからPCBへ、sshも行いましたが、正しくsshログインできました。ネットワークを調べられるところは調べます。もしくは、私が今までの設定で勘違いしているところがあるのか、、ちなみに、現在、ブリッジアダプターでネットワークを割り当てていますが、他の割り当てをすると変わることはあると思いますか？

Comment: metropolisさん　現在、windows10は、有償のセキュリティソフトを使って、それがfirewallを管理していますが、切られていることは確認できました。

Comment: すみませんがネットワーク方面はあまりお力になれません。PCBに6002番ポートでアクセスできるかの確認として「nc -vz PCBのアドレス 6002」をPCAから実行してみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: 結果として、xeyesが表示されました。Virtual Boxのfirewallを完全停止させると上手くいきました、、。h.tokiさんのアドバイスを参考に、PCAで「nc -v PCBのアドレス 6002」でポートの疎通を確認すると、「No route to host」というエラー通知が表示されました。ポートレベルで疎通ができないこと、またPCBで「ss -tlpn　| grep 600」を行った結果で、Address Portの結果が「*6002」であったことが気になっていました（特定のIP番号（PCBのアドレス）に対して6002が接続されるべき？）。とりあえずできたので良かったのですが、現状ではPCBで特定のポートに対して、疎通してxeyesを起動したわけではないのでそれを引き続き目指したいです。

Answer (score 0):

Xサーバは一般的な「サーバ/クライアント」モデルから想像するのと違い、以下のような構成になります。

- 手元で操作する側 (GUIを表示する): Xサーバ
- 表示対象のプログラム: Xクライアント

仮に「PCA から PCB にリモート接続して、PCB 上で実行した GUI を PCA の画面に表示したい」であれば、以下のような流れになります。(ファイアウォール周りなどの細かい部分は解決済みとして)

- PCA 上で X Server を起動しておく (Linux であれば、恐らく GUI ログインしていればOK)
- PCA から PCB に ssh でリモート接続
- PCB 上で 環境変数 DISPLAY を設定 (`export DISPLAY=<PCAのIPアドレス>`)
- PCB 上で GUI プログラムを実行
- PCA の画面に GUI が表示される

Comment: cubickさん　XサーバとXクライアントの考えは、通常の考えと逆で未だに不慣れでございます。現状は、cubickさんがおっしゃるのとは逆で「PCB から PCA にリモート接続して、PCA 上で実行した GUI を PCB の画面に表示したい」でした。一度試してみました。結果としては、変わっておりません。

Comment: 「PCA 上で X Server を起動しておく」のあと「xhost +」をやっておいたほうがいいのでは