# linux(CentOS)上でのxhostコマンドをCUIモードでできないか、または、サービスの自動起動でxhostを設定できないか

Tags: linux

表題についてお聞きしたいです。目的は、リモートでXClientから、XServerにxeyesアプリを表示したいからです。

以前、XClientからXServerにxeyesアプリの表示方法についてはお聞きしましたが、今回は、事前にXserverのサービスを自動起動しており、操作端末もXtermではなく、CUIモードで行おうとしています。

**関連質問:**
[LinuxをもつPCが2台で、リモートアクセスにより、Xアプリの1つ「Xeyes」を表示させる方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75976)

Xserverのファイル内容は以下です。

**/etc/systemd/system/Xserver.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=X server
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xorg -broadcast -keeptty -retro -listen tcp dpms vt7 v -allowMouseOpenFail -allowNonLocalXvidtune 
#Restart=always
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

以下を参考に作成、起動しています。

- [Systemdを使ってさくっと自作コマンドをサービス化してみる](https://qiita.com/DQNEO/items/0b5d0bc5d3cf407cb7ff)
- [ラズパイのX端末化【大幅改訂版】](https://qiita.com/kakinaguru_zo/items/ce6e36765baa9b31d974)

自動起動できるようになると、Linuxの画面は縞模様の画面になっており、TeratermからそのLinuxを操作しています。
操作端末はCUIモードとなっています。尚、この状態でxinitすると、既にXServerのサービスから立ち上がっているため（？）行うことができません。
そして、XServer用Linuxは、特定のXClientとなるホストから接続をするために、Xhostコマンドを入力したところ行うことができません。

その時の結果が以下です。

```
[root@localhost ~]# xhost +
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ""
```

CUIモードでは厳しいと思い、XServerの起動時にXhost設定をすべきと考え、xinitrcスクリプトにxhostコマンドをべた書きして試しました（xhost +と記入）。
XClientをもつターミナルからXServerへ、以下のようにしましたが、XServer上で行ったxhostは反映できていないかと思われます。

```
[root@localhost ~]# export DISPLAY=XServerPCのアドレス:0.0
[root@localhost ~]# xeyes
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display "=XServerPCのアドレス:0.0"
```

以下を参考にしています。

[How to automatically run xhost +servername after boot up](https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/How-to-automatically-run-xhost-servername-after-boot-up/td-p/2970186)

そもそも、xhostコマンドは、基本的にXが立ち上がってから入力できるかと思います(CUIモードでxinitを行った後)。
XServerのサービスが起動していても、画面がCUIの場合厳しいのでしょうか？
また、自動起動設定で、xhost設定できる方法は何かあるのでしょうか？

お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: xhostのエラーはエラーを見る限り、DISPLAY変数が未定義のため発生と思います。Xサーバ側でXサーバが起動している状態でDISPLAY変数を設定してxhost実行してはどうでしょうか。

Comment: h.tokiさん　いつもお世話になっております。XServer側で、「export DISPLAY=XServerのアドレス:0.0」を行いました。そして、XServer側で「xhost」を行いました。結果として、同じエラーが返りました。CUIのモードで行っておりますが、、

Comment: xhostコマンドはXライブラリを使ってXサーバのアクセス制御を設定するコマンドなのでCUIモード(=Xサーバ非動作状態)では動きません。xhostを使うのであれば「~/.xsession」ファイルに書き込むとかでしょうか(gnomeなど使っていると記載すべきファイル変わりそうですが)。あるいはすでに回答のついている方法を試すとかでしょうか

Comment: そうでしたか、、ちなみに質問で記載したXServerのサービスは起動しております。CUIモードですが、Xサーバ動作状態になっていると思っておりますが、CUIのモードは変更する必要があると思います、、？

Comment: Xサーバのサービスが起動しているCUIモードというのが理解できませんでした。とりあえずXorgが起動していないのであればxhostは使えません。

Comment: https://qiita.com/kakinaguru_zo/items/ce6e36765baa9b31d974 に少し記載されていますが、gnomeのような端末を表示せず、Xサーバだけが動作している状態を作れました。また、Taichi Yanagiyaさんの方法で、CUIモードでもxhostできるようになりました。恐らくXorgも起動しているのではと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man Xservers` によると DISPLAY 番号 **n** に対応する /etc/X**n**.hosts ファイルに接続を許可するホスト名、または、IPアドレスを記載すると良いようです。

(/etc/X0.hosts 設定例)

```
local:
192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Taichi  Yanagiyaさん　ありがとうございます！この設定を行い、XServerのサービスを起動しなおしたところ、xhostコマンドをCUIモードで入力可能となりました！また、リモートでXServerにxeyesアプリを表示できました！