# XServerのサービスのエラー「localhost.localdomain Xorg[8254]: XDM: too many retransmissions, declaring session dead」について

Tags: linux

表題について、解決する方法があるかお聞きしたいです。
現在、Linux環境で、Xserverのサービスを作成し、起動している状態です。
方法は、以下の関連質問と少し重複しますが、記述させていただきます。

関連質問：[linux(CentOS)上でのxhostコマンドをCUIモードでできないか、または、サービスの自動起動でxhostを設定できないか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77462/linuxcentos%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AExhost%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%92cui%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF-%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%A7xhost%E3%82%92%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B)

XServerサービスファイルを以下のように作成します。

```
[Unit]
Description=X server
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.targetコードをここに入力
 
[Service]
Type=exec
ExecStart=/usr/bin/Xorg -broadcast -keeptty -retro -listen tcp dpms vt7 v -allowMouseOpenFail -allowNonLocalXvidtune 
#Restart=always
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

以下を参考に作成、起動しています。起動すると、Linuxの画面自体は縞模様の画面となり、何も押しても反応しない状態となります（ディスプレイマネージャが起動していないため？）。
表示としては問題ありません。またteratermでリモートで操作しています。

[Systemdを使ってさくっと自作コマンドをサービス化してみる](https://qiita.com/DQNEO/items/0b5d0bc5d3cf407cb7ff)

[ラズパイのX端末化【大幅改訂版](https://qiita.com/kakinaguru_zo/items/ce6e36765baa9b31d974)

問題点として、現在、XServerサービスのステータスを確認すると（コマンド：systemctl status Xserver.service）
表題のようなエラーが起動後しばらくしてから数分ごとに発生します。また、画面も更新され初期状態になります。
例えば、現在XClientとなるLinux機器からアプリをリモートで、XServer側に表示させようとしておりますが、XServerの画面が更新され、XClient側のアプリも落ちてしまう状況が発生します。

今回、ディスプレイマネージャーを起動していないが、XServerがディスプレイマネージャーに接続しようとするため、このようなエラーが表示されるのではないかと考えております。
XServerがディスプレイマネージャーに接続しない方法を考えましたが、今のところ分かっていません。何か方法はあるでしょうか？また、その他解決できる方法はあるでしょうか？

お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: よくわかりませんがディスプレイマネージャを使用したくない理由があるのでしょうか(xdmはXサーバのデフォルトのディスプレイマネージャです)。

Comment: h.tokiさん　いつもお世話になっております。画面を縞模様画面にしたいことが理由です。縞模様画面にする方法が、今の方法しか考えられませんでした、、xdmを上げると縞模様画面でなく、Xが起動されたログイン画面に切り替わるのでしょうか、、